# How can I know if an entity is a queue or an auto attendand in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, telephony

I am querying a Teams customer via Graph, and when I download a record for a call through the Call Record API, I see many participants, each of them referenced by their ID.
Some of them appear to be call queues or auto attendants, and if I ask Teams for their `/user` I will get a record like:

```
    %{
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
        businessPhones: [],
        displayName: "Phone Menu",
        givenName: nil,
        id: "xxxx-xxxx-451a-b6a9-ab6ab32744c0",
        jobTitle: nil,
        mail: nil,
        mobilePhone: nil,
        officeLocation: nil,
        preferredLanguage: nil,
        surname: nil,
        userPrincipalName: "phonemenu.pbx@customer"
      }
```

I can tell that this is a queue or an auto-attendant by looking at their name, but is there a better way of knowing this is not a human?

Answer (score 1):

You can expand `sessions` which represents a list of sessions involved in the call.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/{id}?$expand=sessions
```

[Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-session?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) has `caller` and `callee` properties of [endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-endpoint?view=graph-rest-1.0) resource type.

`Endpoint` has property `userAgent` of [userAgent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-useragent?view=graph-rest-1.0) type. The [clientUserAgent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-clientuseragent?view=graph-rest-1.0) and [serviceUserAgent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/callrecords-clientuseragent?view=graph-rest-1.0) types inherit from this type.

If `userAgent` is `serviceUserAgent` type then you can check property `role`. Some of possible values should be `skypeForBusinessCallQueues` and  `skypeForBusinessAutoAttendant`.

Comment: Thanks - that's what we have been doing so far. But I was wondering if there was a way to fetch all queues, without respect to them being in use or not. I know this is possible via shell, but not sure if this can be done via Graph.